# php code secuirty?

Tags: php, security

If anyone can suggest secuirty techniques for php coding? how to make your 
php code more secure ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Never trusting the user**, and each project having clearly defined data flows where input from the user is sanitized as soon as possible (preferably before any chance of output)

Always using some form of [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). (In other words never ever using raw SQL). Mistakes have a habit of creeping in when trying to quickly fix bugs.

Never using variables in includes. It may seem like an easy solution, but it is usually a messy one that allows the user to request files they shouldn't.

[Salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) all passwords with a *unique* salt and then hash them, md5() is not an ideal function for this as it has weaknesses.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question, it has been answered a few times..

[Where to begin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325656/php-mysql-security-where-to-begin)

[Books and Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214540/php-security-and-scalablity)

[More resources](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+security)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these key points:

- All data coming from a client can be modified and input should be sanitized/checked before you do anything with it (insert into database, etc)
- Any security related algorithms should be implemented server side, this ensures that the algorithm is executed the way you want it to every time (as apposed to modifiable JavaScript)
- Password hashing or any other form of encryption or hashing should be done within your script and not through other client/server requests (IE: create password hashes before sending them to mysql **DONT** do 'INSERT INTO users VALUES('1','jblow',md5('password'))', as this query is viewable in logs and by administrators of the SQL server
- Last but not least, **DONT BE LAZY** if it takes a bit longer to sanitize input, do it, all it takes is one exploit and your application no matter how amazing it is will loose a lot of its user base.