# Efficient if statement / for loop

Tags: php, coding-style

2 short questions based on trying to make my code more efficient (I think my ultimate quest is to make my entire (fairly complex) website based on some sort of MVC framework, but not being a professional programmer, I think that's going to be a long and steep learning curve..)

1. In this code, is there a way to merge the `if` statement and `for` loop, to avoid the nesting:

   ```
   if($fileatt['name']!=null)
   {
     $attachedFiles = "You uploaded the following file(s)\n";
     for($i=0;$i<count($docNames);$i++)
     {
       $attachedFiles = $attachedFiles. " - " . $docNames[$i] . "\n";
     }
   }
   ```
2. At the moment, I do the fairly standard thing of splitting my $_POST array from a form submission, 'clean' the contents and store the elements in individual variables:

   ```
   $name = cleanInput($_POST['name']);
   $phone = cleanInput($_POST['phone']);
   $message = cleanInput($_POST['message']);
   ...
   ```

(where `cleanInput()` contains `striptags()` and `mysql_real_escape_string()`)

I had thought that keeping all the information in an array might my code more efficient, but is there a way to apply a function to all (or selected) elements of an array? For example, in R, this is what the `apply()` function does.

Alternatively, given that all my variables have the same name as in the `$_POST` array, is there a way to generate all the variables dynamically in a `foreach` loop? (I know the standard answer when people ask if they can dynamically generate variables is to use a hashmap or similar, but I was interested to see if there's a technique I've missed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) To the first question, how to merge the if and the for loop:

Why would you want to merge this, it will only make the code more difficult to read. If your code requires an `if` and afterwards a `for` loop, then show this fact, there is nothing bad with that. If you want to make the code more readable, then you can write a function, with a fitting name, e.g. `listAttachedFiles()`.

2) To the question about cleaning the user input:

There is a difference between input *validation* and *escaping*. It's a good thing to validate the input, e.g. if you expect a number, then only accept numbers as input. But escaping should not be done until you know the target system. So leave the input as it is and before writing to the db use the `mysql_real_escape_string()` function, before writing to an HTML page use the function `htmlspecialchars()`.

Combining escape functions before needed, can lead to invalid data. It can become impossible to give it out correctly, on a certain target system.

Comment: Thanks - I think this is what I thought the answer to 1) would be.  The discussion about 2) is interesting; I actually took inspiration from the cleaning function from http://stackoverflow.com/a/544302/889604 - I'd always assumed that it's best to clean input as soon as possible, although you and @symcbean both say that isn't necessarily correct

Comment: @ChrisW - Yes, it is tempting to write such a "do it once and forget" function, but you can/will get into hot water. Because it is difficult to never forget to escape, you can write a wrapper around the target system, that takes care of the escaping. PHP's [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) library is such a wrapper for database access.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `extract` and combine it with `array_map`

```
extract(array_map('cleanInput', $_POST), EXTR_SKIP);

echo $name; // outputs name
```

Be warned that $_POST `could be` anything and user can then submit anything to your server and it becomes a variable in your code, thus if you have things like

```
if(empty($varName)) { } // assumes $varName is empty initially
```

Could easily bypassed by user submitting `$_POST['varName'] = 1`

To avoid mishaps like this, you can have a whitelist of array and filter out only those you need:

```
$whitelist = array('name', 'phone', 'message');
$fields = array();

foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
   if(in_array($k, $whitelist)) $fields[$k] = $v;
}

extract(array_map('cleanInput', $fields));
```

Comment: OMG - you should *always* use a prefix with extract!

Comment: Thanks - this is very interesting.  I'll definitely use it in conjunction with the points the other respondants have made

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think that the performance cost of using an "If" statement is worth the benefit of having easily readable code.  Also you have to be sure that you actually use fewer cycles by combining, if there is such a way.

I'm not sure I follow your second question, but have you looked at extract() and array_walk() yet?

Answer (score 0):

Point 1 is premature optimization. And you want get any better performance / readability by doing so. (similar for using arrays for everything).

Point 2 - AaaarrgghhH! You should **only** change the representation of data at the point where it *leaves PHP*, using a method *approporiate* to the destination - not where it arrives in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

To make your for loop more efficient **don't use Count() within the condition** of your loops.

It's the first thing they teach in school. As the For loops are reevaluating the conditions at each iterations.

```
$nbOfDocs = count($docNames); //will be much faster
for($i=0;$i<$nbOfDocs;$i++)
{
   $attachedFiles = $attachedFiles. " - " . $docNames[$i] . "\n";
}
```